# Ubuntu boot error: command failed. you need to load the kernal first

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel

When I was booting my Ubuntu system, I would randomly receive the following error:

```
error: Command failed.
error: you need to load the kernel first.
```

I would get this sometimes and the boot would fail, but sometimes the system would boot normally.

There are a lot of questions about the `you need to load the kernel first` error online but none of them helped me as most of them are related to live USB.

Answer (score 0):

So I found out what was causing the issue. It was my Logitech Wireless Mouse. I had it on and connected to my PC always.

Removing the mouse Bluetooth USB while the system was booting did the trick.